# ¿Como puedo hacer para que reconozca "/" al concatenar con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, material-design

Resulta que no puedo hacer que me muestre como una url cuando concateno la url `images/` que es la carpeta que tengo para poner imagenes, el código que armo es el siguiente.

```
carouselImagen+= '<div class="carousel-item active" id="plantillaCarousel">'+
                    '<div class="view" style="background-image: url("images/'+data.carousel[i].imagen+'"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">'+
                    '<div class="mask rgba-black-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">'+
                    '<div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">'+
                    '<h1 class="mb-4"><strong>'+data.carousel[i].tituloImagen+'</strong></h1>'+
                    '<p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">'+
                    '<strong>'+data.carousel[i].descripcion+'</strong></p></div></div></div></div>';
```

si ven bien el la parte `style="background-image: url("images/'+data.carousel[i].imagen+'");` me lo genera de la siguiente manera

```html
<div class="carousel-item" id="plantillaCarousel">
  <div class="view" style="background-image: url(" images="" 1.jpg");="" background-repeat:="" no-repeat;="" background-size:="" cover;"="">
      <div class="mask rgba-black-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">
                <h1 class="mb-4">
                <strong>Titulo de Imagen</strong></h1>
                <p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">
                <strong>Descripcion de la imagen</strong>
                </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Entonces quiero saber si se debe hacer algo para concatenar ahí

> PD: estoy usando jquery y para el diseño usando material design
>   orientado a bootstrap

Comment: ¿Qué tiene exactamente `data.carousel[i].imagen` cuando creas ese texto?

Comment: solo tiene el nombre de la imagen traida desde un json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en la línea que especificas `style="background-image: url("images/'+data.carousel[i].imagen+'");`

Cuando pones `style="background-image:url("` estás cerrando en este punto la etiqueta `style` con las comillas que quieres utilizar para abrir la url.

En principio, yo siempre he puesto la url tal cual, sin comillas ni nada pero entiendo que es mala práctica...  Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

`style="background-image: url(\"images/'+data.carousel[i].imagen+'\");"`

Al poner `\"` le indicas que quieres que esas comillas sean parte del `string` y no que son el cierre de `style`.

Con eso debería funcionarte bien

Comment: gracias a ti lo pude resolver , resulta que también tenia que poner asi esa parte del codigo `style="background-image: url(\'images/'+data.carousel[i].imagen+'\');"` , ya que empezaba con `" "` necesitaba por regla que en url este con comillas simples.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para hacer mas sencillo escribir la cadena, ya que necesitas ambas comillas `"` y `'` ademas de concadenar variables:

```
carouselImagen +=
  `<div class="carousel-item active" id="plantillaCarousel">
     <div class="view"
       style="background-image: url('images/${data.carousel[i].imagen}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
       <div class="mask rgba-black-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
         <div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">
           <h1 class="mb-4"><strong>${data.carousel[i].tituloImagen}</strong></h1>
           <p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">
             <strong>${data.carousel[i].descripcion}</strong>
           </p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>`;
```

Notar que la `url` de `background-image` queda con las comillas simples y la variable es insertada en medio:

```
url('images/${data.carousel[i].imagen}')
```

Comment: probare esto también, te aviso si me funciona.

Comment: funciona tambien gracias, pero un apregunta que soporte tiene esta forma de hacerlo?.

Comment: en general, todos los browsers modernos ya tienen soporte para ES6, pero podrias utilizar un compiler como babel

Comment: Internet Explorer no lo soporta, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Opera y Safari sí